# WebAPI model binding complex object with [FromUri] sent via query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I've read a lot of questions surrounding issues as to why model binding is NOT working, but my question is actually the opposite. I'm curious: Why does model binding to the complex object occur in the following GET action, even when no data is provided in the query string that matches any of the object's properties?

Route configuration:

```cs
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "Items- Get By Client ID",
    "clients/{id}/items",
    new
    {
        controller = "Item",
        action = "GetByClientId",
        constraints = new { id = @"\d+" }
    }
);
```

Query Options class:

```cs
public class QueryOptions
{
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetByClientId(int id, [FromUri] QueryOptions queryOptions = null)
{
    // Operations
}
```

example `GET` use case: `/api/clients/1234/items`

This results in the action, where `// Operations` occurs, having a non-null instantiated object for `queryOptions`, with default values for the properties. In this case, `Skip` & `Take` is `0`.

I would expect `queryOptions` to be `null`, unless those property names were used in the query string, like so: `/api/clients/1234/items?skip=0&take=5`. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: You could try and find the source for the default model binder and work out why! Can't at moment as I'm on phone